# Case insensitive replace all

Tags: javascript

I am looking for any implementation of case insensitive replacing function. For example, it should work like this:

```
'This iS IIS'.replaceAll('is', 'as');
```

and result should be:

```
'Thas as Ias'
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

It would be great to use it with variable:

```
var searchStr = 'is';
'This iS IIS'.replaceAll(searchStr, 'as');
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try regex:

```
'This iS IIS'.replace(/is/ig, 'as');
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9xAse/

e.g:
**Using RegExp object:**

```js
    var searchMask = "is";
    var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");
    var replaceMask = "as";
    
    var result = 'This iS IIS'.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great! But how to use variable instead? `.replace(searchMask, replaceMask)` ?

Comment: @DOTNET Ninja: Updated the post with an example.

Comment: I'd give two upvotes if i could for the second code sample that actually explains what's going on

Comment: Thank you very much buddy! I was trying directly in string.

Comment: the answer is OK, but the performance with regex is very poor versus a classic replace. So would be cool to see a performant variant, not just a short one.

Answer (score 78):

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(strReplace, strWith) {
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/556609
    var esc = strReplace.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    var reg = new RegExp(esc, 'ig');
    return this.replace(reg, strWith);
};
```

This implements exactly the example you provided.

```
'This iS IIS'.replaceAll('is', 'as');
```

Returns

```
'Thas as Ias'
```

Comment: This can also handle cases like: txt.replaceAll("(test12)", "")

Comment: Best solution by far. Works a treat. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 13):

When you use the regex solution you can get problems if your replace string contain e.g. "?". So you have to escape all regex characters or use e.g.:

```
String.replacei = String.prototype.replacei = function (rep, rby) {
    var pos = this.toLowerCase().indexOf(rep.toLowerCase());
    return pos == -1 ? this : this.substr(0, pos) + rby + this.substr(pos + rep.length);
};
```

this will not change all the occurrences of 'is' in the string. Therefore you can write a while loop in the function.

Comment: This is also double as fast than the regexp solution .. see https://jsperf.com/replace-all-case-insenstive/1

Comment: This only replace one time

Answer (score 6):

This is the improvisation from Paul's answer, and there are a performance gap between Regex vs Non-regex

The regex code for comparation is taken Benjamin Fleming's answer..

[JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/replaceall-regex-vs-non-regex)
**Case-sensitive**
Regex: 66,542 Operations/sec
Non-Regex: 178,636 Operations/sec (split - join)

**Incase-sensitive**
Regex: 37,837 Operations/sec
Non-Regex: 12,566 Operations/sec (indexOf - substr)

```js
String.prototype.replaces = function(str, replace, incaseSensitive) {
    if(!incaseSensitive){
        return this.split(str).join(replace);
    } else { 
        // Replace this part with regex for more performance

        var strLower = this.toLowerCase();
        var findLower = String(str).toLowerCase();
        var strTemp = this.toString();

        var pos = strLower.length;
        while((pos = strLower.lastIndexOf(findLower, pos)) != -1){
            strTemp = strTemp.substr(0, pos) + replace + strTemp.substr(pos + findLower.length);
            pos--;
        }
        return strTemp;
    }
};

// Example
var text = "A Quick Dog Jumps Over The Lazy Dog";
console.log(text.replaces("dog", "Cat", true));
```

Comment: Warning: this leads to an infinite loop in case the `str` string is at the very start of the input string.

Comment: Looks like someone already posted the one line fix as a new answer below, actually I will happily accept edit from community to my answer instead

Answer (score 2):

Note there is a bug in an answer provided above.  If your original string starts with the replacement you'll enter an infinite loop.

```
String.prototype.replaces = function(str, replace, incaseSensitive) {
    if(!incaseSensitive){
        return this.split(str).join(replace);
    } else { 
        // Replace this part with regex for more performance

        var strLower = this.toLowerCase();
        var findLower = String(str).toLowerCase();
        var strTemp = this.toString();

        var pos = strLower.length;
        while((pos = strLower.lastIndexOf(findLower, pos)) != -1){
            strTemp = strTemp.substr(0, pos) + replace + strTemp.substr(pos + findLower.length);
            if (pos == 0) break; // Fixes bug
            pos--;
        }
        return strTemp;
    }
};

// Example
var text = "Dog Jumps Over The Lazy Dog";
console.log(text.replaces("dog", "Cat", true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

```
'This iS IIS'.replace(/is/ig, 'as')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to avoid regular expressions due to performance concerns, you might consider implementing a custom function. This custom function can loop through the string, identify matches regardless of their case, and then replace them. But be aware that this approach might not be more performant than using a well-crafted regular expression, especially for large strings or complex replacement patterns.

```
function replaceCaseInsensitive(str, find, replace) {
    let result = "";
    let findLower = find.toLowerCase();
    let index = 0;

    while (index < str.length) {
        if (str.substring(index).toLowerCase().startsWith(findLower)) {
            result += replace;
            index += find.length;
        } else {
            result += str[index];
            index++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Example usage
let originalString = "Hello World";
let newString = replaceCaseInsensitive(originalString, "world", "Universe");
console.log(newString); // Output: Hello Universe
```

Answer (score 0):

Insensitive ReplaceAll:
12 053 033 replaces by 1 sec
for ReplaceAll("Dog Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", "dog", "Cat")

Example:

```
function ReplaceAll(base,told,tnew) { // replace insensitive
  if (told=="") {return base;}
  var u=base.toLowerCase();
  var t=told.toLowerCase();
  var ss=""; var p=-1; var i=0;
  p=u.indexOf(t);
  if (p>-1) {
    let mLen=told.length;
    while (p>=0) {
      ss+=base.substr(0,p)+tnew;
      i=p+mLen;
      base=base.substr(i);
      u=u.substr(i);
      p=u.indexOf(t);
    }
    ss+=base; //fix bug
    return ss;
  }
  return base;
}    
/*Test:
    
    function loopThrough() {
             for (let i = 0; i < 60000000; i++) {
               let s=ReplaceAll("Dog Jumps Over The Lazy Dog","dog","Cat");
             }
          }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
          //alert(ReplaceAll("Dog Jumps Over The Lazy Dog","dog", "Cat"));
          
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '...';
          let startTime = new Date();
          loopThrough();
          let endTime = new Date();
          let timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "elapsed times: " + timeElapsed + " milliseconds.";
*/
```

Comment: How is this better than the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313402/5625547)?

Comment: try the example I show, it probably won't work correctly in the accepted answer by regular expressions

Comment: 'This Beta=? iS IIS'.replace(/beta=?/ig, 'BETA=1');  result incorrect value

Answer (score -2):

I recommend the [str_ireplace](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_ireplace/) function from php.js, which even replaces strings from arrays.

Comment: Using a third-party library for such simple task might be overkill.