# How to make specific word in string upperCase or lowerCase?

Tags: javascript

Okay I have a small problem I want to make specific words in this string to be upperCase() or lowerCase().

This is what I originally tried:

```
function lcFunct() {
        var a = "WelCome TO the Test I WANT all THIS to be LoWeRCAse"
        document.getElementById("tests").innerHTML = a.str.replace(6,12).toUpperCase()
}
```

All I want to know is how to simply make certain words `lowerCase` or `upperCase`.

Comment: You can use regex to find and modify those words, what are the words?

Comment: Certain words? Which ones, exactly?

Comment: Pick Any Two Words if your planning on leaving an example please.. It doesn't matter which two.

Comment: No, we can't leave an example, because you haven't clarified your problem.

Comment: Okay simply I want "Welcome to" to be Lower Case or UpperCase.. but i want to tell it.. after to look like for instance "str.substr(7,6)". i want to select the words like that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this way,for any particular word.
  here is an example using toUpperCase().

```
var text = "WelCome TO the Test I WANT all THIS to be LoWeRCAse";
text=text.replace("WelCome","WelCome".toUpperCase());
```

or this way, here is an example using substring() and toLowerCase().

```
text=text.replace(text.substring(0,7),text.substring(0,7).toLowerCase());
```

Comment: THANKS! Thanks Great Answer! Simple... exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

From a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313402/1445964) in StackOverflow:

```js
var searchMask = "HELLO WORLD";
var str="Look this HELLO WORLD and this hello world and say HELLO WORLD";
var replaceMask = searchMask.toLowerCase();
var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");

var result = str.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
alert(result);
```

You can write "Hello World" or "HellO woRld" and the code works 
in both cases.