# JS Replace - Remove same capitalisation specification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a script that highlights a part of a string by wrapping it in a span. (the part that is highlighted is decided via a form)

Right now I've got this.

```
value.replace(term,'<span>'+term+'</span>')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var term = $('.n').val();
  var matches = ['Tree of life','Life of the tree'];
  $('.output>div').remove();
    $.each(matches,function(index,value){
        $('.output').append('<div>'+value.replace(term,'<b>'+term+'</b>')+'</div>')
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="n" value="Tree">

<h4>Output</h4>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

But thing is, this needs the term to be the same capitalization.

So if I'm searching for Tree:

- **Tree** of life -> has a match
- Life of the tree -> doesn't have a match

So how can I do a replace in JS, but that doesn't take in account the capitalization?

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579). You should try to use DOM methods instead.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/3462319, `var re = new RegExp(term,"gi");`

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm pretty sure OP isn't using regular expressions here, he's just trying to match a string

Comment: Related solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313395/case-insensitive-replace-all)

Comment: @depperm Make sure to escape the `term` if necessary - eg if `term` contains a character with a special meaning in a regex, like `^`, just passing `term` alone will fail

Answer (score 0):

Turn the first argument to `replace` into a case-insensitive regular expression, rather than just a string:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
const escape = s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
const pattern = new RegExp(escape(term), 'i');
const result = value.replace(pattern, '<span>'+term+'</span>');
```

If you want to replace all occurrences, use the `g` flag as well.